# Why is JavaScript not finding the difference between dates?

Tags: javascript, date, object

I am trying to find the difference between two `Date()`s in JavaScript by using the `-` operator. However, it keeps returning `null`. Here is my code:

```js
var date1 = new Date("2020-08-20T08:59:49.765Z");
var obj = {"date1": date1};
sessionStorage.setItem("date1", JSON.stringify(obj));
var retrievedFromStorageD1 = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("date1")).date1;
var now = new Date();
console.log(retrievedFromStorageD1-now);
//in the console: null
```

```html
<script>
/*
Fake sessionStorage object so OP's code deosn't throw in StackSnippet.
This is not part of OP's code
*/
const sessionStorage = {
  storage: {},
  setItem(key,val) {
    this.storage[key] = val + "";
  },
  getItem(key){
    return this.storage[key];
  }
};
</script>
```

What did I do wrong? Anyone have any working code snippets?

Comment: Converting your code to a runnable snippet shows it does not return null.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I edited it so it is a minimal reproducible example. Sorry about that...

Comment: `retrievedFromStorageD1` is a String, not a Date object.

Comment: Despite being closed, this question seems valid to me and has a simple and obvious answer.  I won't post the answer unless/until I can do so in an open question;.

Comment: @Steve I will open a new question so you can post your answer, then, I will post the new question link here so you can post the answer and I can accept your answer

Comment: Actually, @hev1's answer was what I had in mind, so you already have the answer below

Comment: @anonsaicoder9 If the method I provided doesn't work, could you provide a [mcve] of the issue? The code that I have provided in my answer itself runs fine.

Comment: Ok, sure. Give me a sec

Comment: @anonsaicoder9 If you use `var retrievedFromStorageD1 = new Date(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("date1")).date1);`, the code in your question works: https://jsfiddle.net/su5vxagh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should solve your issue...

```js
/*
Fake sessionStorage object so OP's code doesn't throw in StackSnippet.
This is not part of OP's code
*/
const sessionStorage = {
  storage: {},
  setItem(key,val) {
    this.storage[key] = val + "";
  },
  getItem(key){
    return this.storage[key];
  }
};

var date1 = new Date("2020-08-20T08:59:49.765Z").valueOf();
var obj = {"date_1": date1};

sessionStorage.setItem("date_1", JSON.stringify(obj));
var retrievedFromStorageD1 = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("date_1")).date_1;

var now = new Date().valueOf();

console.log(retrievedFromStorageD1 - now);
```

Comment: `new Date().valueOf()` is a long way of doing `Date.now()`. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

When the objected was stringified, the `Date` was converted to a string. You can use the `Date` constructor to get the Date itself.

```
var date1 = new Date("2020-08-20T08:59:49.765Z");
var obj = {"date1": date1};
sessionStorage.setItem("date1", JSON.stringify(obj));
var retrievedFromStorageD1 = new Date(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("date1")).date1);
var now = new Date();
console.log(retrievedFromStorageD1-now);
```

Comment: It would be easier to store `date1` as a number, instead of converting it back and forth.

Comment: @Kosh that would anyway be stored as a string and you would still convert back and forth from that representation to a Date object JSON.stringify on a complete datastructure is simpler.

Comment: @Kaiido, it's much easier. E.g. `sessionStorage.setItem("date1", +date1); console.log(+sessionStorage.getItem("date1"))` Also JSON parse/stringify is a performance killer =))

Comment: They have a dictionary `{ date1: the_date }` not just the raw date value. And if you face a perf issue with JSON.parse/stringify you must be dealing with MBs of data and you'll probably not want to convert all these values to Date objects.

Comment: @Kaiido, why do you think it's a feature (the dictionary)?

Comment: Because it's way better to have a clean storage with a complete dictionary per key rather than having thousands of keys per single values. This code is obviously an MCVE.

Comment: @Kaiido, I may be wrong, but in this example I see the opposite -- unnecessary dictionary with one key-value pair =))

Comment: @Kosh in the real program, the JSON that is contained within localStorage has a LOT more data.

Comment: @hev1 when I put in my code, it returns syntax error:

VM18:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: @anonsaicoder9 Please provide a [mcve]. That looks like you are trying to parse `undefined`.

Comment: @anonsaicoder9, thank you for clarification. Wish you've solved your problem soon. hev1's solution should work, though it's not optimal, IMHO.